# Changing target audience will update live ad?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

What if I increase the target audience with a new user? Will live ad be notified about it? Or do I need to delete the ad, and create it anew based on the new target audience?

Answer (score 0):

From the API Documentation for the [Ad Object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup#Updating)'s update operation

> Use fields you used to Create Ads, including status and
>   execution_options. You cannot use adset_id and social_prefs.

So, short answer, you can update an existing ad and it should be reflected right away (you can make a GET request to verify)